# Global Hook KeyBoadr in TService

Tags: delphi-xe

I want to write Global Hook. As an application, the code below works. But not as a service.

```
function TrapKeyboardInput(nCode: integer; wp: wParam; lp: lParam): LResult; stdcall;
// Windows Hook Procedure To Intercept Keyboard Input
begin
    // This Structure is Defined By The Windows API
    if nCode < 0 then
        Result := CallNextHookEx(hook_Keyboard, nCode, wp, lp)
    else
    begin
        if nCode = HC_ACTION then
        begin
            SecondInactionHO := 0;
            Result := 0;
        end
        else
            Result := 0;
    end;
end;

procedure StartHock();
begin
    hook_Keyboard := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, @TrapKeyboardInput, HInstance, 0);
end;
```

Comment: You can't hook the mouse/keyboard from a service. A service runs in a different session than user logins, and mouse/keyboard interactions are session-specific. So, you would have to hook them in each session and use an IPC mechanism to send the information to your service. But, why do you need your service to hook the mouse/keyboard at all? What is it going to do with that information? This sounds like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).